# while (end of array) - how to recognize

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, while-loop

I have an array of numbers {1,2,3,4,5} or an array of chars or whatever. I want to a write a template method to print out the full array. It works, there are just some problems. Maybe i post first the code:

```
template <typename A>
void printArray(A start) {
    int i = 0;
    while (start[i] != 0) {
        std::cout << start[i] << std::endl;
        i++;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    using namespace std;
    int xs[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}; //works
    //int xs[] = {1,0,3,6,7}; of course its not working (because of the 0)
    int *start = xs;

    printArray(start);

    return 0;
}
```

Can you see the problem? `while(start[i] != 0)` is not the best way to read an array to end ;) What do I have for other options?

Thank you!

Comment: You're not passing an array, you're passing a pointer.

Comment: Don't treat ordinary arrays as C-style null terminated arrays.

Answer (score 12):

***Option 1:*** pass a pointer and the number of elements

```
 template<class T>
 void doSth(T* arr, int size)
```

**Upside** - will work with both dynamic and automatic arrays.
**Downside** - you must know the size. You must pass it.

***Option2:*** parametrize the template with the size which will be auto-deduced

```
template <class T, int N>
void doSth(T(&arr)[N])
```

**Downside** - Dynamic arrays cannot be passed

***Option 3:*** Be a good programmer and use `std::vector`'s

Comment: All sound solutions, but the advice is the best part.

Answer (score 11):

Since you are using C++, a `vector<int>` and `iterators` will do you better over the long haul.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use array, not pointer, then you can write the function template as:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
void printArray(T (&start)[N]) 
{
    int i = 0;
    while ( i < N) {
        std::cout << start[i] << std::endl;
        i++;
    }
}

int xs1[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}; 
int xs2[] = {1,0,3,6,7}; 
printArray(xs1); //okay
printArray(xs2); //okay

int *start = xs1;
printArray(start); //error - cannot pass pointer anymore!
```

So better solution would be  : `std::vector<T>`.

Or even better use range *(pair of iterators)* which is very idiomatic, as:

```
template <typename FwdIterator>
void printArray(FwdIterator begin, FwdIterator end) 
{
    while (begin != end) {
        std::cout << *begin << std::endl;
        begin++;
    }
}

int xs1[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}; 
int xs2[] = {1,0,3,6,7}; 
printArray(xs1, xs1 + sizeof(xs1)/sizeof(xs1[0])); //okay
printArray(xs2, xs2 + sizeof(xs2)/sizeof(xs2[0])); //okay

int *start = xs1;
printArray(start, start + sizeof(xs1)/sizeof(xs1[0])); //okay!
```

`printArray` now can be use with `std::vector<T>` also:

```
std::vector<int> vec; //you can use std::list as well!
//populate vec

printArray(vec.begin(), vec.end());
```

Comment: Two comments: unless you count on using it with several different types of containers, there's no point in making it a function template; a normal function will do.  And secondly, of course, rather than `xs1, xs1 + sizeof(xs1)/sizeof(xs1[0])`, you want the usual `begin(xs1), end(xs1)`.

Comment: @James Kanze: 1) OP has used template, so I made this template as well, assuming he wants to make it work for many different types.2) `std::begin()` and `std::end()` is available with C++0x which I didn't assume in my solution. :-)

Comment: OK then for the templates:-).  As for `begin` and `end`, I (and I doubt many others) didn't wait for the standard.  It's been more or less standard in most people's toolkit for over 10 years now.

Comment: @James: That is true. Utility such as `begin` and `end` can be implemented with much less effort, even in C++03.

Answer (score 2):

Pass both the address of array and its length.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a compile-time array, you can do this with a template:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
static inline void print_array(const T (&a)[N])
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    std::cout << a[i] << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  int a[] = {1,2};
  print_array(a);
}
```

If all you need is to *print* arrays, also check out the [pretty printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850473/pretty-print-c-stl-containers), which uses this sort of stuff internally.

Comment: @iammilind: And Armen beat me to it by 30 seconds, too :-)